Draw custom extrude shapes
I'm a Maya user trying to transition to Blender.  Pretty awesome so far.  I'm seeing this video here in the link below.
I'm curious on how this artist is creating these custom shapes and quickly extruding them into another object.  Looks as if the person is simply drawing on top of a face and extruding.  Unsure how though.  Any direction would be great.  This would be such a time saver.
https://www.instagram.com/reel/C47vSwQqzWw/
Thank you all :)

It's hard to say, it could be the Knife tool, or maybe a custom tool. You would have a better chance by asking them directly. We don't clearly see which tool is used.

That is probably using Box Cutter addon or similar featured addons

Ok, thank you both.  This provides me with some direction as to what to search.  I'll also try asking them and see what they say.  I'll post here if I get a response in case.
